# How to initiate events based on stopwatch timer?

Tags: android, eclipse, chronometer

Basically I'm working on an application that alerts drivers how long they have been driving. It requires alerts at certain times.

At the moment I'm using a chronometer that displays time passed.

As one hour passes I need a message to appear on screen saying 'Hour Passed'.

As 2 hours passes I need another message saying 'Hour Passed' and a further message saying 'A 15 minute break is required'. Then a button needs to appear that allows the user to start a break which until starts a new chronometer.

When the break is complete at 15 minutes, a button needs to appear that says 'continue driving' and the original chronometer displaying driving time needs to continue from the time it was at before the break (2:00:01).

As you can see all the functionality is relatively similar, based on time events.

I'm guessing I need to use some sort of if statements that are initiated when the chronometer reaches a certain time but I'm basically stuck on how to make the application do the required functionality when the chronometer reaches a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at the AlarmManager class to run an intent a certain amount of time after the time the stopwatch is started.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the alarm manager with a pending intent.Create a receiver that catches the pending intent action and do whatever you want to do.
You can either register a broadcastreceiver from your app when it is started(preferred way in your case) or create a broadcastrecievr and create a intent filter in the manifest file...In this case the event would be catched even if your app is not running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I'm pretty new to android development but I've given what you said a go.

The problem at the moment is I'm not sure what code to use to do:

if chronometer is equal to 01:00 { do pending intent action }

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Your question is not clear(" if chronometer is equal to 01:00 { do pending intent action } Any ideas?")...please give more inputs on what you had done and what is the problem??

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Im basically trying to follow that (NUMBER  4 ON TUTORIAL) but displaying 'Hour passed' as the message and without the vibrate function. However, the tutorial uses a user input for the number of seconds before the text is displayed. What I want is the text to display when the chronometer is displaying a certain time e.g. 1 hour.

Comment: I've got the text saved in a MyTimeReceiver class - Toast.makeText(context, "Hour Passed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

I then have an activty called startAlert in the main file which is called in the main.xml file - android:onClick="startAlert"

If you look at the tutorial link, startAlert can be seen under the last code sample of number 4. The code at the moment is receiving an integerinput by the user and then when that time has passed a message is being displayed. I need some help adapting that code to display a message when the chronometer reaches a certain time.